# How to get Client Secret in Basic Authentication working for OpenIddict ClientCredential grant type?

Tags: asp.net-core, openiddict, clientcredential

I have configured an authorization server for ClientCredentials using OpenIddict as follows.

```
services.AddOpenIddict()
    // Register the OpenIddict core components.
    .AddCore(options =>
    {
        // Configure OpenIddict to use the Entity Framework Core stores and models.
        // Note: call ReplaceDefaultEntities() to replace the default entities.
        options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
            .UseDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
    })
    // Register the OpenIddict server components.
    .AddServer(options =>
    {
        // Enable the token endpoint.
        options.SetTokenEndpointUris("/connect/token");

        // Enable the client credentials flow.
        options.AllowClientCredentialsFlow();

        // Register the signing and encryption credentials.
        options.AddDevelopmentEncryptionCertificate()
            .AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();

        // Register the ASP.NET Core host and configure the ASP.NET Core options.
        options.UseAspNetCore()
            .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough();

        options.DisableAccessTokenEncryption();
    })
    // Register the OpenIddict validation components.
    .AddValidation(options =>
    {
        // Import the configuration from the local OpenIddict server instance.
        options.UseLocalServer();

        // Register the ASP.NET Core host.
        options.UseAspNetCore();
    });
```

I can get the access_token when the client_id and client_secret are in the body of the request.
[access token returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAZ55.png)

```
[12:20:27 INF] HTTP POST /connect/token responded 400 in 377.3274 ms
[12:21:22 INF] The request address matched a server endpoint: Token.
[12:21:22 INF] The token request was successfully extracted: {
  "grant_type": "client_credentials",
  "client_id": "PVHP",
  "client_secret": "[redacted]"
}.
```

But it does not work when the client_id and client_secret are sent as Base64 encoded client_id:client_secret in the Basic Authorization header. The grant_type=client_credentials is specified in the body.
[error using basic auth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c28OU.png)

```
[12:21:23 WRN] Client authentication failed for PVHP.
[12:21:23 ERR] The token request was rejected because the confidential application 'PVHP' didn't specify valid client credentials.
[12:21:23 INF] The response was successfully returned as a JSON document: {
  "error": "invalid_client",
  "error_description": "The specified client credentials are invalid.",
  "error_uri": "https://documentation.openiddict.com/errors/ID2055"
}.
```

The openid configuration doc seems to indicate client_secret_basic is supports

```
[11:18:01 INF] The response was successfully returned as a JSON document: {
  "issuer": "https://localhost:44371/",
  "token_endpoint": "https://localhost:44371/connect/token",
  "jwks_uri": "https://localhost:44371/.well-known/jwks",
  "grant_types_supported": [
    "client_credentials"
  ],
  "scopes_supported": [
    "openid"
  ],
  "claims_supported": [
    "aud",
    "exp",
    "iat",
    "iss",
    "sub"
  ],
  "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": [
    "RS256"
  ],
  "subject_types_supported": [
    "public"
  ],
  "token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
    "client_secret_basic",
    "client_secret_post"
  ],
  "claims_parameter_supported": false,
  "request_parameter_supported": false,
  "request_uri_parameter_supported": false
}.
```

Have I missed any configuration when setting up the server?
Regards.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the basic authentication header is correctly formatted? Both the client_id and the client_secret must be URL-encoded before being base64-encoded.

Comment: Found the issue. My client_secret has a  '+' in it. I need to url encode it. Once that is done, the client_secret is correctly decoded from the base64 encoded header.  Decided to change the client_secret. 
Thanks.

Comment: I had \r\n added to client secret as in fiddler I had extra new line, so be careful